# Cannot set active camera to view for a large object

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Haven't worked with Blender in ages, but this is the first time I experience that "Align active camera to view" does not work.

So, I make a cube 100 x 20 x 10 mm in Freecad, and export as Wavefront obj; here it is `Unnamed-Cube.obj`:

```
# FreeCAD v0.19 build24276 (Git) Arch module
# http://www.freecadweb.org
mtllib Unnamed-Cube.mtl
o Box
usemtl color_cccccc
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 0.0 0.0 10.0
v 0.0 20.0 0.0
v 0.0 20.0 10.0
v 100.0 0.0 10.0
v 100.0 0.0 0.0
v 100.0 20.0 0.0
v 100.0 20.0 10.0
vn -1.0 0.0 0.0
vn -1.0 0.0 0.0
vn 1.0 0.0 0.0
vn 1.0 -0.0 0.0
vn 0.0 -1.0 0.0
vn 0.0 -1.0 0.0
vn 0.0 1.0 0.0
vn 0.0 1.0 0.0
vn 0.0 0.0 -1.0
vn 0.0 0.0 -1.0
vn 0.0 0.0 1.0
vn 0.0 0.0 1.0
f 1//1 2//1 3//1 
f 3//2 2//2 4//2 
f 5//3 6//3 7//3 
f 5//4 7//4 8//4 
f 6//5 5//5 1//5 
f 1//6 5//6 2//6 
f 8//7 7//7 3//7 
f 8//8 3//8 4//8 
f 3//9 7//9 1//9 
f 1//10 7//10 6//10 
f 8//11 4//11 2//11 
f 8//12 2//12 5//12
```

Now I open Blender 2.82 (sub 7). I delete the default cube, then I go File / Import / Wavefront (.obj), and import the above file. First view I get is this:

[image: blender first import]

Apparently, I'm looking inside the object, so I navigate the view to the outside:

[image: blender navigate out]

Here I issue View / Align View / Align Active Camera to View ... and, I get this:

[image: blender not all shown]

I really have no idea how even this portion of the box is shown - I've repeated this experiment at least three times until now, and I always got a blank screen so far.

So how the hell can I get the damn camera to show what I'm seeing in the viewport? I just want to have a simple rendering damn it, and I cannot do it without the damn camera ...

Comment: Select the camera, press G and move the mouse to centre your object in the view. There's a quick recent YT video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sDZ0zRVn1M). It's for Blender 3, but should be the same in 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected functionality. The only extra component is that the camera clipping distance is much lower than the viewport clipping distance, so the farther away parts of the cube disappear. Increase the camera’s clipping distance in the Properties editor.